# How to create an aggregate based on unique elements as fields?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to aggregate documents based on diagnosisType, and at a higher level `patientKey` and `encounterKey`. This is what the documents look like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("...."),
    "patientKey" : 1,
    "encounterKey" : 2,
    "diagnosisType" : "medical_history",
    "diagnosisCode" : "Z87.81",
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("...."),
    "patientKey" : 1,
    "encounterKey" : 2,
    "diagnosisType" : "problem_list",
    "diagnosisCode" : "2x.2",
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("...."),
    "patientKey" : 1,
    "encounterKey" : 3,
    "diagnosisType" : "medical_history",
    "diagnosisCode" : "D21.01",
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("...."),
    "patientKey" : 1,
    "encounterKey" : 3,
    "diagnosisType" : "medical_history",
    "diagnosisCode" : "X2.31",
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("...."),
    "patientKey" : 1,
    "encounterKey" : 3,
    "diagnosisType" : "problem_list",
    "diagnosisCode" : "p.2342",
}
```

This is what I would like the aggregate to look like:

```
{
    "patientKey": 1,
    "encounters":[{
                   encounterKey: 2,
                   medical_history: [Z87.81],
                   problem_list: [2x.2]
                  },
                  {
                   encounterKey: 3,
                   medical_history: [D21.01, X2.31],
                   problem_list: [p.2342]
                  }]
 }
```

Any ideas how I could approach this?

I have tried the following for medical history and then problem list, my initial thought is to first aggregate on Problem List and then on Medical History, then combine the collections, afterwards do another aggregate based on encounters, and then finally another aggregate on patientid.

But it's a problem combining heterogeous documents.

```
db.collections.aggregate([
{$match:{diagnosisType:"Problem List"}},
{$group:{_id:"$encounterKey",
         "ProblemList": {$push:{$concat:"$diagnosisCode"}},
         "durableKey":{$first:"$durableKey"}}},
{$project:{_id:0,
            encounterKey:"$_id",
            ProblemList:1,
            durableKey:1}},
 {$out:"output"}
],{
allowDiskUse: true
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { patientKey: "$patientKey", encounterKey: "$encounterKey", diagnosisType: "$diagnosisType" },
            problem_list: { $push: "$diagnosisCode" }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { patientKey: "$_id.patientKey", encounterKey: "$_id.encounterKey" },
            encounters: { $push: { k: "$_id.diagnosisType", v: "$problem_list" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            encounters: { $arrayToObject: "$encounters" }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.patientKey",
            encounters: {
                $push: {
                    encounterKey: "$_id.encounterKey",
                    problem_list: "$encounters.problem_list",
                    medical_history: "$encounters.medical_history"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            patientKey: "$_id",
            _id: 0,
            encounters: 1
        }
    }
])
```

Basically you need few [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) stages to accumulate the data. Additionally you have to use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) to build your JSON keys dynamically.

Outputs:

```
{
    "patientKey" : 1,
    "encounters" : [
        {
            "encounterKey" : 2,
            "problem_list" : [
                    "2x.2"
            ],
            "medical_history" : [
                    "Z87.81"
            ]
        },
        {
            "encounterKey" : 3,
            "problem_list" : [
                    "p.2342"
            ],
            "medical_history" : [
                    "D21.01",
                    "X2.31"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```